# Save grayscale video in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save a video as `.avi` format but i keep getting the error `"could not demultiplex stream"`. I primarily want to save grayscale videos.

Is there any specific `codec` i need to use?

Right now i tried with `XVID, DIVX`

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

interval = 30
outfilename = 'output.avi'
threshold=100.
fps = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, nchannels = frame.shape

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter( outfilename,fourcc, fps, (width,height))

ret, frame = cap.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

while(True):

  frame0 = frame

  ret, frame = cap.read()
  frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
  frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

  if not ret:
    deletedcount +=1
    break

  if np.sum( np.absolute(frame-frame0) )/np.size(frame) > threshold:
    out.write(frame)
  else:
    print "Deleted"

  cv2.imshow('Feed - Press "q" to exit',frame)

  key = cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF

  if key == ord('q'):
    print('received key q' )
    break

cap.release()
out.release()
print('Successfully completed')
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal, complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: I updated the code, Can you help me figure it out

Comment: The video compiles and runs properly and gives the proper console o/p when i insert `print` statements but the o/p i get cannot be read it gives `"Could not demultiplex stream."`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Windows OS try:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(outfilename, fourcc, fps, (width, height), 0)
```

Comment: worked on Linux too (Ubuntu), by adding the "zero" argument at the end

Comment: this work for me as long as the frame that passed into `out.write(frame)` is already converted to gray scale

Answer (score 6):

It is possible that `.DIVX` is looking for a 3-channel BGR image to write, but you're only providing it a single channel image, since you're trying to write a grayscale image

Try doing this:

`frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)`

essentially this will try to convert your greyscale image to BGR image. While your pixel values will remain gray, this will change `frame` to a 3-channel image

Comment: It works on one computer but didn't on the other. Maybe codec issue?

Comment: Considering the OP code, it means there are two consecutive conversions, `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` then `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`. I was looking for a shortcut, say something like `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY2BGR` , but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 things to keep in mind when you are trying to write Grayscale image in video writer.
1.   while reading the image,keep 0 followed by ','

```
image = cv2.imread("data/PCB.jpg",0)
```

2&3. While creating the video writer, declare shape in opposite way and keep 0 followed 
     by ',' as we did in step 1

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (image.shape[1],image.shape[0]),0)
```