# OpenCV video not getting saved

Tags: python, opencv, mplayer

I am trying to save a video in OpenCV but i keep getting the error `"could not demultiplex stream"`. I then checked size and found out that it was in `kB`. I primarily want to save grayscale videos how do i make it possible?

Is there any specific `codec` i need to use?

```
mplayer gives the following output

MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing output.avi.
libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3
AVI file format detected.
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
AVI: Missing video stream!? Contact the author, it may be a bug :(
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (mpeg4), -vid 0
VIDEO:  [MP4V]  1280x720  24bpp   -nan fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 encoder: Lavf54.20.4
Load subtitles in ./
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 54.35.1 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.35.0
Unsupported AVPixelFormat 53
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
V:   0.0   0/  0 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Right now i tried with multiple codec formats

```
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

interval = 30
outfilename = 'output.avi'
threshold=100.
fps = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, nchannels = frame.shape

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter( outfilename,fourcc, fps, (width,height))

ret, frame = cap.read()
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

while(True):

  frame0 = frame

  ret, frame = cap.read()
  frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
  frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

  if not ret:
    deletedcount +=1
    break

  if np.sum( np.absolute(frame-frame0) )/np.size(frame) > threshold:
    out.write(frame)
  else:
    print "Deleted"

  cv2.imshow('Feed - Press "q" to exit',frame)

  key = cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF

  if key == ord('q'):
    print('received key q' )
    break

cap.release()
out.release()
print('Successfully completed')
```

Comment: Near exact duplicate of [Save grayscale video in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037063/save-grayscale-video-in-opencv) posted few hours ago by the same user. Please, [edit] the original, rather than spamming the site with identical questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: The out.avi was previous non working file.The new output.avi is working file]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',-1, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        out.write(gray)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Try this one
Select Intel iyuv codec.
The out.avi is non working file.
The output.avi is new working file.

Comment: No again video is not getting saved. Same o/p as above.

Comment: Can you open that video and play it? For me it's coming "could not demultiplex stream"

Comment: For me still no, Which OS, OpenCV version and python version? I'll try setting up the proper environment.

Comment: python:3.6.4   opencv=3.4.0    os: windows 10

Comment: Oh okay, i'm running ubuntu 14.04 python 2.7 and OpenCV 2.4.13. Maybe that's why.

Comment: Just update your python and openCV. I think that will be enough. If not set  a virtual environment and try. If it worked please mark my ans as accepted :)

Comment: I am setting up a conda env to see it.

Btw to read files other than webcam on this environment is FFmpeg required?

Answer (score 0):

If video is not getting saved, possibly the reason may be its **capture size** which is hardcoded as `(640,480)`.

**You can try the below code:**

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc_codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
fps = 20.0
capture_size = (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)))

out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc_codec, fps, capture_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if you are passing the correct shape, do it like this:

1. `h, w, _ = frame.shape`
2. `size = (w, h)`
3. `out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 30, size)`